# Parsing Failed: JSONDecoder Swift

Tags: json, swift, decode, jsonresponse

I'm trying to decode a json request using Alamofire 5.2
The problem is that I use JSONDecoder and I have some issues about the conversion

The API is in Spanish and my models in English so I decided to changed this kind of values using an enum of keys

But I don't know if this works... Here's my code:

API RESPONSE: (json variable)

```
    {
  "sistemaOperativoId" : 0,
  "nombreUsuario" : "Coasnf_09",
  "menus" : [

  ],
  "acciones" : [

  ],
  "fechaRegistro" : "2020-04-15T09:46:24.0573154",
  "empresa" : null,
  "version" : null
}
```

MY MODEL:

```
struct UserP: Decodable{
    var username : String
    var company : String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case username = "nombreUsuario"
        case company = "empresa"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        username = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .username) ?? "null"
        company = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .company)  ?? "null"
    }

    init(username: String, company: String){
        self.username = username
        self.company = company
    }
}
```

CONVERTION:

```
   func login(user: User) -> UserP? {
        var userData: UserP! = nil
        AF.request(UserRouter.login(user: user)).responseJSON{ response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let response):
                print(response)
                let dict = (response as? [String : Any])!
                let json = dict["data"] as! [String: Any]

                if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json , options: .prettyPrinted)
                {
                    do {
                        var jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                        print(jsonString)
                        userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserP.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
                        print("Object Converted: ", userData.username)
                    } catch {
                        print("Parsing Failed: ", error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }



                break

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                break
            }
        }

        return userData
    }
```

Comment: What is `User`? Where is `json` being set? Why do you use both `JSONSerialization` _and_ `JSONDecoder`?

Comment: `print("Parsing Failed: ", error.localizedDescription)` => ùprint("Parsing Failed: ", error)

Comment: @Larme "Parsing Failed:  No se pudo leer los datos porque no se encontraron."

Comment: @Gereon "User" doesn't really matter because I used it to get json in a response

Comment: Show the code where you get `json`, then. The encoding to a string and then decoding to a `UserP` seems redundant - why can't you simply pass the JSON data you get to `JSONDecoder.decode()`?

Comment: Because I have another Structure and I converted into a simple structure that you can find in  "API RESPONSE" section. BTW I updated my method

Comment: The code is so strange. You are mixing JSONSerialization & JSONDecoder. You are converting like two or three times going from "Data to Swift Dict" and back and so on... What print `print(jsonString)`? And what's do `print(error)` and not localizedDescription.

Comment: Try to decode jsonString using my model. That's the only problem

Comment: you don't need `let dict = (response as? [String : Any])!`, just `let json = response.data` would suffice. But then again I suspect one more problem here `company = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .company)  ?? "null"`

Comment: @staticVoidMan I think the problem is on the keys. I found this https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/lets-parse-the-json-like-a-boss-with-swift-codable-protocol-3d4c4290c104 and I used "Scenario 2"

Comment: `CodingKeys` are fine, your decoder logic is not. that is problem #2 that you will face after fixing the Alamofire logic

Comment: if `nombreUsuario` and `empresa`  are not guarnateed to come in the json then it should be optional and then your decoder should have something like `company = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .company)`

Comment: It was helpful and works... Thanks a lot! @staticVoidMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Alamofire logic related change:

`response` from `Alamofire` has a `data` property that you can use directly:

```
let json = response.data
do {
    let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserP.self, from: json)
    print(user)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

Furthermoe, if the keys `nombreUsuario` and `empresa` are not guaranteed to come in the json then recommended way is to mark those variables as optional. With this you don't need the custom decoder logic.

#### Model Change #1:

```
struct UserP: Decodable {
    var username: String?
    var company: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case username = "nombreUsuario"
        case company = "empresa"
    }
}
```

---

#### Model Change #2:

If you want to give some default values then a custom decoder can help:

```
struct UserP: Decodable {
    var username: String
    var company: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case username = "nombreUsuario"
        case company = "empresa"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        username = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .username) ?? "Default Name"
        company = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .company) ?? "Default Company Name"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @AntonioLabra My pleasure :) NOTE: if you mark those as optional then you don't need the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` unless you want to give an explicit default value. For completeness sake, I have updated my answer to show both scenarios.

Comment: @staticVoidMain talking about Alamofire request how can I fixed it? because it has issues and doesn't return my object converted

Comment: @AntonioLabra What are you getting vs what are you expecting?

Comment: I'm getting my request but it returns "nil" by first time. It seems like it's not an Async function

Comment: @AntonioLabra What returns nil. Anything specific? Any error messages?

Comment: Without error messages. The problem is that returns nil and the first time when I launch the function and It's strange because enters when I give the error to the Interface

Comment: I'm trying to use "completionHandlers" but I don't know if its possible. I'm having: "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completionHandler"

Comment: @AntonioLabra If you have to update UI, like reload table or something then you probably need to do that within `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: my  AF.request()... starts after I have a "nil" result and this returns

Comment: @AntonioLabra That sounds like an entirely different problem. Post another question with details specific to the new problem you have. I will take a look at it later :)